# Socket Exceptions observed during Load Testing

Tags: c#

We are conducting load test using VSTS 2010 for a particular application and we are observing a lot of socket exceptions with the error:

> Exception SocketException A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond **.**.***.**:443.

With the stack trace:

> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)  at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout,
>   Exception& exception)

We have 2 agent machines through which we are conducting the load test. We are unable to figure out if its problem with the agent machines or network issue.

Comment: Does this only occur under load?

Comment: Check if it is not a problem with application pool `queueLength` limit, [here is a tutorial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441171(v=office.13).aspx)

Comment: @ Jordell...Yes it happens only under load

Answer (score 0):

Under heavy load, both the client and server sides of a socket can easily timeout because not enough CPU (or network) is available to process the packets.  It's impossible to tell from the client side whether it was a client-side or a server-side issue because they both appear as a lack of response in the specified time.  You have to have sufficient CPU and threads on both sides to send all the requests and process responses in a timely fashion. In the case of a load test, you're presumably pushing it harder and harder until something fails, and you want the server side to be the one that fails (otherwise you simply found the limits of your load tester rather than the server code).  In order to make that happen, you'll need to closely monitor the load testing (client) side to be sure it's not running out of CPU (or threads or network bandwidth).

Answer (score 0):

This is an IP-Address issue,It's not maintaining your IP-Address constantly.So,I think its better to go with Application Insights help for solving this issue.

Comment: I do not see how your content is *answering* the question. If at all, it would be a mediocre comment, but it is nowhere close being an **answer**.